# ¿Como pasar de int a char array?

Tags: java, array, poo

tengo que hacer un programa en el que debo crear un array que contenga letras de la `'a' a la 'z'`.

Ingresar números por teclado y por cada numero que vaya ingresando se ira generando un carácter con la letra asociada al indice del `array`. 
El ingreso de valores finaliza cuando ingrese `-1` .

Al terminar debe mostrar la cadena construida.

El problema es que necesito encontrar la forma de pasar un `int` a `char` `array` , asi por cada numero que ingrese se forma una letra , luego a esa variable `int` ya convertida en `char` la paso a `string` para ejecutar la cadena formada.
intente poner la variable letra de la siguiente manera :

`letra=(char[])numero;` y no me deja , me sale que no se puede realizar eso de un `int` a un `char[]`.

Ahora les dejo el codigo , si me puede decir si hay una forma de solucionarlo gracias :)

```
    public class ArrayChar{

private char [] letra = {'a' ,'b' , 'c' ,'d' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' , 
                          'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n', 'o' , 'p', 
                         'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' , 'u' , 'v', 'w', 'x','y', 'z'};

private int numeros ; 

public ArrayChar(int numeros){

this.letra = new char [numeros];
this.numeros = numeros;

}

public String crearCadena(){

    return (String.valueOf(this.letra));
}



}

    import java.util.Scanner;
public class PruebaArrayChar{

    public static void main (String [] args){

  int numero = 0;

  Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

  while(numero!=-1){

    System.out.println("Ingrese un numero :");
    numero = teclado.nextInt();
    ArrayChar arrayChar1 = new ArrayChar (numero);
    if(numero==-1){

        System.out.println(arrayChar1.crearCadena());
    }

  }



    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayChar arrayChar1 = new ArrayChar (numero); Estas creando un nuevo array cada vez que se ingresa algo

Answer (score 0):

Para contestar tu pregunta:

Para pasar de un `int` a una a letra en el char array (`char[]`) de la forma en que te lo piden (el `int` es la posición en el char array), lo haces usando el `int` como subindice del `array`.

Recordá que la primera posición en un array es 0 por lo que si el número ingresado cuenta las letras desde 1 en adelante tenes que restarle 1 al valor ingresado.

Ejemplo:

```
char [] arrayDeLetras = new char[] {'h','o','l','a'};
String lasVocales = "";
lasVocales = lasVocales + arrayDeLetras[1] + arrayDeLetras[3];
```

Respecto a tu programa me parece que lo tenés que volver a re-pensar porque como están armadas las clases y como están trabajando juntas no hacen sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Tu arreglo `letra` es de longitud 26 desde 0 hasta 25, entonces si ingresas un número por teclado, lo restas 1 y eso haría referencia a la posición del arreglo, también creas un `ArrayList` para ir agregando las letras según el número ingresado.
Te dejo un ejemplo con solo 1 clase creada, los atributos son `static` debido a que va ser usado dentro de un método static.

```
public class ArrayChar{    

    static char [] letra = {'a' ,'b' , 'c' ,'d' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' , 
                              'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n', 'o' , 'p', 
                             'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' , 'u' , 'v', 'w', 'x','y', 'z'};
    
    static List<String> palabra= new ArrayList<>();
    
    static void crearCadena(int numero){
        palabra.add(String.valueOf(letra[numero-1]));//El arreglo va desde 0 por eso se resta 1        
    } 
    
    static void mostrarPalabra(){
        System.out.print("Palabra generada: ");
        for(String s:palabra){
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    } 

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numero;     
        System.out.print("Ingrese un numero entre (1-26): ");
        numero = teclado.nextInt();
        
        while(numero!=-1){
          crearCadena(numero);
          System.out.print("Ingrese un numero entre (1-26): ");
          numero = teclado.nextInt();          
        }  
        mostrarPalabra();
    }
}
```